# \begin{enumerate}[(a)] does not indent items

Tags: enumerate

How can I indent letter items using the method expressed in the title:

```
\documentclass[12]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\section*{Greetings}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]

\item Hello World % I am not indented 
\item Halo Welt 
\item Ciao mondo
\item Ola` mundo
\item Hola mundo

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The current output would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: It is not complete. It doesn't compile: \documentclass and other things are missing.

Comment: Note that the option is `12pt`, not `12`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That behavior is part of how `enumerate` sets things up: take or leave.

I suggest to use `enumitem` with its full power (no `shortlabels` option), it is much more flexible and customizable; for alphabetic enumeration use `\alph*`. I present three examples:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\section*{Greetings}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item Hello World % I am not indented
\item Halo Welt
\item Ciao mondo
\item Ol\`a mundo
\item Hola mundo
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),leftmargin=2\parindent]
\item Hello World % I am not indented
\item Halo Welt
\item Ciao mondo
\item Ol\`a mundo
\item Hola mundo
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),leftmargin=*,align=left]
\item Hello World % I am not indented
\item Halo Welt
\item Ciao mondo
\item Ol\`a mundo
\item Hola mundo
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Note that `showframe` is just to show the page frame and so the alignment with respect to the left margin (made visibile).

Note also that the font size option is `12pt` and not `12` (which is ignored).

[image]

Answer (score 15):

You can add spacing commands to the label definition:

```
\documentclass[12]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\section*{Greetings}

\begin{enumerate}[\hspace{2cm}(a)]
\item Hello World % I am not indented
\item Halo Welt
\item Ciao mondo
\item Ola` mundo
\item Hola mundo
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

As you wish (Additional `A` only to show the indentation).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\section*{Greetings}

A

\begin{enumerate}[\indent(a)]

\item Hello World % I am not indented 
\item Halo Welt 
\item Ciao mondo
\item Ola` mundo
\item Hola mundo

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Replace loading `enumerate` with `enumitem` and `shortlabels` option:

```
\documentclass[12]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section*{Greetings}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]

\item Hello World % I am not indented
\item Halo Welt
\item Ciao mondo
\item Ola` mundo
\item Hola mundo

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]