# How to get three nested enumerations in LaTeX?

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, enumitem, sharelatex

This is my current code. I've managed to get one next enumeration but I want a third nesting to replace me having to write 1.1.1, 1.1.2 etc.

```
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item Top Levek
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item Second Level
     \begin{enumerate}
     \item Third Level
     \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}
```

This gives me

```
1 Top Level
1.1 Second Level
i Third Level
```

My desired output is

```
1 Top Level
1.1 Second Level
1.1.1 Third Level
```

How do I achieve this?

Also, how do I remove the indentation on the third level so it is inline with the second level?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Ehen you post a question it's better to give a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). This should be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem *and* compile. This both clarifies your question and makes it easier to help you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us if your document loads any packages that influence the appearance of numbers used in enumerations. For sure, the LaTeX default for second-level enumerated items is `(a)`, `(b)`, etc., *not* `1.1`, `1.2`, etc. Please also advise whether or not second-level enumerated items should be left-indented with respect to first-level enumerated items.

Comment: What should be inline with the second level? The label or the texts that follow the labels?

Comment: @Bernard the answer given is what I was looking for. However, if you know how to get both the labels in line with each other and the text in line with each other also that'd be great.

Comment: If you'd asked for this alignment of the labels in the OP then that's what I would have given...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it this alignment you wish?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\newlength{\labelwd}
\settowidth{\labelwd}{9.9.9}
\setlist[enumerate]{label*=.\arabic*, wide = 0.5em, labelwidth=\labelwd}
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate, 2,3]{labelindent=-\dimexpr\labelwd+\labelsep}

\begin{document}

 \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\labelwd+\labelsep + 0.5em,]
    \item Top Level. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Second Level. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.
        \begin{enumerate}%[labelindent = -\dimexpr1cm + \labelsep]
        \item Third Level. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.
        \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to produce:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\theenumi.\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\theenumii.\arabic*}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item Top Levek
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item Second Level
     \begin{enumerate}
     \item Third Level
     \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The important bits are the lines

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\theenumi.\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\theenumii.\arabic*}
```

These specify what you want the labels to look like. I highly recommend reading the package manual if you need to tweak further. It's very to easy to read.

**Edit** TO get the indentation in the OP you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{
   leftmargin=0pt, labelindent*=0pt, labelwidth=0pt,align=left
}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\theenumi.\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\theenumii.\arabic*}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item Top Level
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item Second Level
     \begin{enumerate}
     \item Third Level
     \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

to give:

[image]

**EDIT II**  As Mico says in the comments, for the required indentation it is easier to use `\setlist[enumerate]{ wide=0pt }`.

Comment: Why not use `\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\arabic*.}` instead?

Comment: This solution doesn't address the OP's objective to "remove the indentation on the third level so it is inline with the second level".

Comment: @leandriis - The OP has stated that he/she does *not* want a period (aka "full stop") at the end of the numeric labels.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for that. I did not know about `label*`!

Comment: Simpler than `leftmargin=0pt, labelindent*=0pt, labelwidth=0pt,align=left` is `wide=0pt`.

Comment: @Mico Hi Mico, yes I agree, that's definitely better. I was surprised that I had to go to such lengths to get this...another case of user error:)

Comment: Good work. _See also_ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203885/beginenumeratea-does-not-indent-items

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a new package, you can define new list environnement.

With my ugly solution, if you write nothing after an item and you open a new list just after, the numbers appears only one time, like show here:

[image]

LaTeX render this very well, but I do it without any care.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{123num}
\newenvironment{123item}
  {\begin{list}{\textbf{\arabic{123num}}}
               {\usecounter{123num}
                \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.4em}
               }}
  {\end{list}}

\newcounter{sous123num}
\newenvironment{sous123item}
  {\begin{list}{\textbf{\arabic{123num}.\arabic{sous123num}}}
               {\usecounter{sous123num}
                \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.8em}
                \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.9em}
               }}
  {\end{list}}

\newcounter{soussous123num}
\newenvironment{ss123item}
  {\begin{list}{\textbf{\arabic{123num}.\arabic{sous123num}.\arabic{soussous123num}}}
               {\usecounter{soussous123num}
                \setlength{\labelwidth}{2.7em}
                \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.9em}
               }}
  {\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\begin{123item}
 \item Top Level
   \begin{sous123item}
   \item 
     \begin{ss123item}
     \item Third Level
     \end{ss123item}
   \item Second Level
   \end{sous123item}
 \end{123item}

\end{document}
```